# Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula for Multiple Sums

Tags: calculus

The Euler-Maclaurin summation formula is
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k = a}^{b} f(k)  = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt  + B_1 (f(a) + f(b)) + \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!} ( f^{(2n-1)}(b) -  f^{(2n-1)}(a) )  + R_{N},
\end{eqnarray}
where $B_{n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$-Bernoulli number taking $B_{1} = \tfrac{1}{2}$, and the remainder term is bounded by the following
\begin{align}
|R_{N}| \leq    \frac{|B_{2N} |}{(2n)!}  \int_{a}^{b} | f^{(2N)}(t) | \, dt.
\end{align}
for any arbitrary positive integer $N$. Is there a similar formula for nested sums of the form,
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k_1 = a_1}^{b_1} \cdots \sum_{k_n = a_n}^{b_n} f(k_1, \dots, k_n).
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks!

Comment: These papers discuss this and related:  https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0608/0608171v1.pdf , https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0507/0507572v2.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! There's a [whole chapter](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=tofDpuuEDu4C&pg=PA166) about it in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=tofDpuuEDu4C).

Comment: The formula there (say in Theorem 2 there) is stated only for the case when $f$ is an exponential function. In fact, the Todd operator (in terms of which the formula there is stated), seems to be only defined on functions $f$ of the form $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n^n z^n/n!$ with bounded $c_n$'s -- so that such functions are somewhat like the exponential functions.Strangely enough, the domain of the operator is not specified there.

Comment: I meant Theorem 10.2 there in the book.