# Asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{n = 2}^{x} \frac{1}{\log(n)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}}$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, asymptotics

Presumably
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}(x)  = & \sum_{n = 2}^{x} \dfrac{1}{\log(n)}+ O(\log(x))\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}(x)  = & \int_{2}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\log(t)}\operatorname{d}t 
\end{align}
By Euler-Maclaurin approximation
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 2}^{x} \dfrac{1}{\log(n)}   \approx &
\int_{2}^{x} \dfrac{1}{\log(t)} \operatorname{d}t  + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\log(2)} + \dfrac{1}{\log(x)}\right) \\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\log(2)} + \dfrac{1}{\log(x)}\right)=O(\log(x))
\end{align}

I am having greater difficulty calculating the error term ($e$) for

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}}+e
\end{align}

though, since it is a nested sum. I looked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30384/euler-maclaurin-summation-formula-for-multiple-sums), but am struggling a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference:
$$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log t}-\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log n},$$
regarded as the approximation error for a Riemann sum, is bounded by:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{x}\left|\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\right|\leq\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}\leq\frac{1}{\log^2 2}\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{n}=O(\log x).$$
Moreover:
$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)+O(1/k^2)\right)=\log(n+1)+O(1)=\log(n)+O(1)$$
gives that:
$$\frac{1}{\log^2 n}\ll\left|\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{H_n}\right|\ll\frac{1}{\log^2 n},$$
hence you just have to estimate
$$\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log^2 n}$$
to find the error term in last formula.

Comment: thanks for your help on this